# Right to left languages - list of language options

Tags: user-expectation, language, human-interface-guideline

I am redesigning setting options for mobile application. One of them is "edition" which includes many languages and also Right to Left languages. Currently it is in a list where LtR languages are aligned left but the other RtL languages are are aligned to the other side and it just looks sh*t. There is also flag to represent each edition. example:

[flag] International__________

[flag] America______________

[flag] India_________________

[flag]_________________עברית

My question is, would they understand if this was aligned left ? Should I be thinking of different solution for example making it into a grid ? How well do RtL languages read if they are aligned to the centre if it was to be made into a grid? The only thing I read about RtL languages is from the google material design doc that they published but it says nothing about when both RtL and LtR are displayed at the same time. Are there any other guidelines written for this ? Also if the user was to change the edition to Right to Left language edition, would they expect the other labels to be aligned right then ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a language picker where the RTL languages were aligned to the right and the LTR languages to the left. I've seen plenty where they were all aligned to the left. Have you seen anything different that prompted your question?

Comment: Hi matt, I am trying to come up with best possible solution that would work across both LtR and RtL. Surely it is not natural for RtL language users to see their own language aligned left. Thats why I am trying to think of a solution that would work for both. But then again I dont know if RtL languages ever align stuff in centre. They are quite a big market for  the company I work for so I am trying to come up with best solution.

Comment: I just wonder why the problem hasn't been solved before, if it is indeed a problem. Looking at big examples like Microsoft, Apple, Google, Twitter, Facebook, Wikipedia etc, none of them align RTL languages to the right and LTR languages to the left in their language picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly understandable, see wikipedia
[image]

Comment: Cool and I assume in RtL language all other language options will be RtL as well

Comment: yea, just like wikipedia